# Is it possible to create new objects in runtime in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, oop

From my colloquial understanding of creating new objects from classes in Javascript one can do the following line of code:

`const exampleVariable = new exampleClass("ExampleArguement");`

I apologize for this being a novice question but is it possible to create new objects within the execution of the program? Sort of "automating" the creation of objects in my code.

Let's say I need to create 100 objects.

I *could* technically write 100 lines initializing variables and their respective objects but I am **100%** sure there is a more efficient way of doing this.

I tried looking up a solution but I couldn't quite get the phrasing right so I would appreciate it if someone pointed me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Comment: How about using for loop for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loops for that.

For example:

```js
class SomeClass{
    constructor(id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

const objects = [];
const amountOfObjects = 100;
// create objects
for (var i = 0; i < amountOfObjects; i++){
  const object = new SomeClass(i + 1);
  objects.push(object);
}
 
// iterate over the array of objects created and log their id
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
  console.log(objects[i].id);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is a very intuitive answer to my question. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, I would appreciate if you can accept my answer if you found it suitable

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object in run-time. Just with:

```
const myObject = {};
```

Or you can use the constructor if you're more used with classes:

```
const myObject = new Object();
```

Finally, answering your question, in run-time you can create 100 objects, for instance, inside of an array or another structure:

```
const myArray = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
  const myObject = { index };
  myArray.push(myObject)
}
```

With this code you will have `{ index: 0 }` inside of `myArray[0]`. Then, you have 100 possible variables inside the whole array.

Hope it helps.